# Teradata SQL: Extract time from Timestamp

Tags: sql, teradata

When dealing with a Timestamp like '29-03-2021 15:30:02', I'm usually using operators like:

```
Year(Timestamp) AS Event_Year
Month(Timestamp) AS Event_Month
Week(Timestamp) AS Event_Week
Hour(Timestamp) AS Event_Hour
```

But this time I need to extract the time, having a column with `'15:30:02'`.

I was thinking about something like `Time(Timestamp) as Event_Time` but it doesn't seem like a command. Is there any smart solution to come across this?

Comment: Be very careful about time zone side effects if you are using TIME (without TIME ZONE) data type; you won't want to use TIME for calculations or comparisions. And if it's for display, why not just extract the substring and leave it as a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's already a `Timestamp` data type, you can use `cast` like this:

```
CAST(fieldname AS TIME)
```

Or if it's still a string, you would have to do this I think:

```
CAST(CAST(fieldname AS TIMESTAMP FORMAT 'dd-mm-yyyyBhh:mi:SS.s(1)') AS TIME)
```

(I forget the proper syntax for the timezone identifier)

Comment: That was quite simple, and it works perfectly. Thanks @simplycoding